# RSA1 key file issues when sshing to localhost on a port other than 22?

Tags: macos, ssh, port-forwarding, x-windows

I'm trying to set up an X11 tunnel on Mac OS X Lion with (in one terminal):

```
ssh -L 2222:<remote machine>:22 <gateway server to remote machine>
```

This bit works fine and I get logged on to the gateway server, with (I guess) traffic arriving at my local port 2222 redirected to port 22 on the remote machine.

Then, in a second terminal, I try:

```
ssh -X -p 2222 localhost
```

but I get permission denied when I'm asked for my password (that of localhost, my MacBook Pro).
The odd thing is that I can "ssh localhost" with no problem at all.
If I add -vvvv to the last command, some key errors appear:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /Users/<my username>/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In logs, you always search for the first line containing the error.

```
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /Users/<my username>/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
```

It tells you that the key file is incorrect, so you should verify if it is indeed a RSA1 key file.

[man ssh-keygen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) might help you create this file properly...

Comment: Thanks, but if I can ssh localhost (without using port 2222), doesn't that suggest the key is OK?

Comment: @user293594: Perhaps local users don't need to be verified? Not sure, but it is an issue to be solved.